# How to generate multiple components with React HOC?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have to generate few components with the same UI.

I want all the UI to be generated by the HOC
BUT
The data should be passed directly from the child components without the use of props.

For eg,

```js
const HOC = WrappedComponent => {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>/*Component Name passed here*/</h1>
      <p>Data: /*Some Data passed here*/</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My child components will look like so,

```js
import Data from //path

const Component1 = () => {}

expord default HOC(Component1)
```

And lets say my Data is imported from a file like so,

```js
const data = [
  {
    comName: //some name,
    data: //some data
  },
  {
    comName: //some name,
    data: //some data
  },
  {
    comName: //some name,
    data: //some data
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can pass Data as second parameter with component:

```
export default HOC(Component1, Data)
```

and use data in HOC:

```
const HOC = (WrappedComponent, data) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>/*Component Name passed here*/</h1>
      <p>Data: /*Some Data passed here*/</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your method does pass the data but I get this error. "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`."